# Asp Clássico - Salvar página com MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0

Tags: asp, cache

Boa tarde, estou tentando criar um sistema de cache para meu site e para isso estou usando o objeto MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 desta forma:

```
Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

url = http://siteexemplo.com.br/teste.asp
objHTTP.open "GET", url, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
objHTTP.send() 'ocorre o erro

txt = objHTTP.responseText
Response.Write(txt)
```

Se eu executar o código numa página estática ele grava o arquivo normalmente, porém, se eu executar em uma página que traz as informações de um BD ocorre o seguinte erro.

> msxml6.dll error '80072ee2' The operation timed out
>   /_includes/cache_top.asp, line 46

A linha 46 é o "objHTTP.send()".
Se eu testo no meu servidor local, que tem o IIS7 instalado em um windows professional, ele funciona normalmente, porem, quando tento usar no meu servidor web que tem o IIS7 instalado em um servidor com Windows Serve, o erro ocorre ;(

Li em alguns lugares que NÃO deveríamos usar o "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP", como neste link da Microsoft por exemplo: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/316451

Mas... Se eu não usar este componente, de qual outra forma eu poderia estar trabalhando para gravar uma página em um arquivo?

Ou... como eu soluciono o problema do MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0

Comment: acho que isso dai já está obsoleto, e você já baixou o sdk https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4608

Answer (score 0):

Já tive problemas com isso e consegui criar o objeto usando umas dessas duas formas:

```
Set oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

Varia conforme a versão do IIS